# Open a program (VLC) and move it to the foreground

Tags: command-line, osx, video, background-process, vlc

On a Mac, specifically, when I use the `VLC` command line to open a video file, it opens in the background by default. How can I instead move it to the foreground whenever I run the command to open a video?

Comment: I have this problem too. I can't use `open -a` because that won't allow me to use `--fullscreen`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --fullscreen ~/trash/temp.m3u
```

It was not coming to the foreground when it was failing to load the first file in my m3u playlist.